# Calculating a volume from a 3D matrix

Tags: machine-learning

There is a boundary map between a 2D image and a 3D image. Let's say the sun light shines behind you and your shadow projects in front of you - in the plane. There is a boundary match between yourself (3D object) and your shadow (2D image).

Now let's say I want to know what is the volume of head from the information of your shadow image.
let's assume I am able to segment or isolate the image shadow of your head. How can I calculate the volume of your head image? Thanks.

Comment: I could make a cardboard cut out of you that casts the identical shadow for a given position of the light, and the cardboard cut out has effectively 0 volume.  You will need to make some additional assumptions.

Comment: If you let the sun shadows through a 2D grid screen, or if a laser grid screen illuminates a 3d shape, yes, from different angle looking you could estimate your 3d shape. But how? i have the same answer. It is an interesting application i want to apply also.